# Assert the range of a binomial coefficient divided by power of a number

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I found this question in a previous year post graduate entrance exam for mathematics.The question was 
What is the range of
\begin{equation*}
\frac{200 \choose 100}{4^{100}}
\end{equation*}

The choices were 
\begin{align*}
[\frac{3}{4}, 1) && \text{or} &&(0, \frac{1}{2}) && \text{or} && [1, \infty) && \text{or} && [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4})
\end{align*}

Comment: Showing the result is less than $1$ is easy but to determine which interval is correct seems difficult. Perhaps you may use the expression $\binom{2n}{n} \sim 4^n/\sqrt{\pi n}$. This is asymptotic but strongly hints that $(0,1/2)$ is the correct interval... This result can also be obtained applying the better known Stirling Approximation, but again the result would be asymptotic unless you know specifics of the error terms.

Comment: Nitpick;  $\frac {200 \choose 100}{4^{100}}$ is a specific value. It doesn't have a range because it has no variance.  Do you mean "which of the following intervals contain the value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Compare $\binom{200}{100}$ with $\sum_{k=0}^{200}\binom{200}k$.

This in the understanding that: $$\sum_{k=0}^{200}\binom{200}k=2^{200}=4^{100}$$

Comment: Do you mean compare like $4^{100}=\sum_{k=0}^{200} \binom{200}{k} < 201 \binom{200}{100}$?

Comment: More something like $4^{100}=\binom{200}{100}+\sum_{k=0,k\neq100}^{200}\binom{200}{k}$. The second term on RHS is much larger than the first. Divide both sides by $4^{100}$ and you get $1=a+b$ with $a$ smaller than $\frac12$ and $b$ larger than $\frac12$. You are looking for an estimation of $a$, so...

Comment: Right but that still technically falls under the category of furious handwaving right :p Intuitively it is clearly true of course

Comment: For making it rigorous it is enough already to prove that $\binom{200}{99}+\binom{200}{101}=2\binom{200}{99}>\binom{200}{100}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+...+\binom{n}{n}=2^n$$ so you can rewrite
$$\begin{equation*}
\frac{200 \choose 100}{4^{100}}=\frac{200 \choose 100}{2^{200}}=\frac{200 \choose 100}{\binom{200}{0}+\binom{200}{1}+\binom{200}{2}+...+\binom{200}{100}+...+\binom{200}{199}+\binom{200}{200}}<<1
\end{equation*}$$
you can make a sence by looking at pascal's triangle
$$1\\1\space 1\\1 \space 2 \space 1 \\
1 \space 3 \space 3 \space 1\\1\space 4\space 6 \space 4 \space 1\\1\space 5 \space 10 \space 10 \space 5\space 1\\1\space 6 \space 15 \space 20 \space 15\space 6 \space 1$$ for example at $n=4\to  \frac{6}{16}<\frac8{16}$
and $n=6\to  \frac{20}{64}<\frac 13$
and so on

Answer (score 0):

Write the expression as $$\frac {200!}{(2^{100}\cdot 100!)(2^{100}\cdot 100!)}$$
The first term in the denominator cancels all the even factors in the numerator, leaving us with
$$\left(\frac{199}{200}\right)\left(\frac{197}{198}\right)\left(\frac{195}{196}\right)\ldots\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
The last factor is $\frac 12$ and all the rest are less than $1$, so the product is less than $\frac 12$